# Vue.jsと比べてNuxt.jsがどう違うのかがわかりません

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

以下の点以外で何か違いはありますか？
・サーバサイドレンダリングが簡単にできる
・vue-routerとvuexの設定が楽にできる

Answer (score 2):

NuxtJS は Vue.js プロジェクトのバックボーンであり、柔軟でありながら自信を持ってプロジェクトを構築するための構造を提供します。

**主な機能**

1. コードを自動的に分割すること
2. サーバーサイドレンダリング
3. 非同期データをハンドリングするパワフルなルーティング
4. 静的ファイルの配信
5. ES2015+ のトランスパイレーション
6. JS と CSS のバンドル及びミニファイ化
7. 開発モードにおけるホットリローディング
8. プリプロセッサ: Sass, Less, Stylus など
9. HTTP/2 push headers ready
10. モジュール構造で拡張できること